# How to make the value of a variable inside a Java Private method available/visible to another java file?

Tags: java

I have a Private method in a java file within which I have a variable called maxRate. I need the value of maxRate in another java file to compare it with another variable minRate.

How do I make the maxRate variable visible to another java file?

My code is as follows
    A.java (in a diff package)

```
public class A{

  private Integer maxRate = null;

  private modelAndView dConfig(int a,string b,string c, string d, string e){
    Map<String, PropConf> map = getConf(b,c,d,e);
    PropConf propConf = map.get(getKey(a));
    Integer maxRate = propConf.getMaxRate();
  }
}
```

Problem:
I need the value of maxRate in B.java which resides in a different package.

Progress:

As of now as per suggestions, I declared maxRate as private Integer maxRate on the top within the public class A{ and have also declared a getter method in A.java as follows,

```
public Integer getMaxRate(){
return this.maxRate
}
```

then I tried calling getMaxRate from within B.java as follows,
    B.java

```
public ModelAndView save() {

A a = new A();
Integer f = a.getMaxRate();
logger.debug("F is" +f); }
```

The f value was printed as null.

Comment: You cant access variables initialized in a Private Class outside of the class you need to initialize it as a Global Variable then.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get to the internals of the method. Either make it a class level field with an associated getter, or return it from your method.

Comment: returning the value is a good alternative, if making the field class level is not viable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable outside of your private function and define it as public. You can also define it outside of your private function (keeping it private) and then add a public getter and/or setter.  Since the more obvious public getting/setter methods, and public class variable options are covered in other answers, here is much less common and more convoluted way to extracting a private field from a class.  First the variable must be declared outside of the private function fields inside functions aren't even accessible from reflection (maybe with a project that reads Java byte-code):

```
Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("maxRate");
f.setAccessible(true);
Integer secretInt = (Integer) f.get(obj);
```

Comment: Besides a public getter and setter and a public field, the only other way would be with reflection

Comment: May I ask what language you are more familiar with?  It might help me answer your question if I understood what language capabilities you are expecting Java to have.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But if teaching, why not teach properly? It takes _exactly_ the same amount of effort to do it right than to do it wrong, given the knowledge it takes is present in the teacher!

Comment: I used to feel the same way about public fields, I guess JavaScript has spoiled me :P

Comment: Also, please refrain from suggesting reflection to novice coders, when the problem is of completely different nature. OP is clearly not in the ballpark to realize the power this would give him, and would probably cause way more trouble, than he - and his future colleagues - will have. This question is not about how to reach a private variable's value in a Class you can't change. Your approach is a last resort type, if there is a chance, this should not be used under any circumstances! Would _you_ like to work with code, that does _this_? I bet not.

Comment: Thanks Jason. But I wont be able to define the variable outside of the private method because I am setting the value of maxRate from the output of another function within the private method

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a method variable from another method except you are calling the method2 inside ***dConfig*** and passing the variable directly to method2.

```
private modelAndView dConfig(){

    method2(maxRate);

}
```

A possible solution to your problem could be the following...

You can make the variable maxRate a private class variable:

```
private Integer maxRate = 9;
```

the add a public getter method:

```
public Integer getMaxRate() {
    return this.maxRate;
}
```

Edit for updates:

Your code should look like this:

```
public class A {

  private Integer maxRate;

  public A() {
    this.maxRate = 9; //Initialize of the variable
  }

  public Integer getMaxRate() {
    return this.maxRate;
  }
}
```

As i said in my comment, seems you are missing the initialize part of your variable.

Comment: When I try to declare maxRate as private, I am getting an error stating "Illegal modifier for parameter maxRate only final is permitted".

Comment: @Stalwart araknoid meant that the line beginning with private be inserted **outside** the methods of your class. Please see my answer, that has it all detailed.

Comment: Thanks Araknoid/ppeterka. I actually tried the above approach but when I try to print the maxRate value from b.java through the logger statement, I am getting only null and not the exact maxRate value which I am retrieving in a.java. My private method and maxRate variable in a.java is defined as below,  private modelAndView dConfig(){
    maxRate = pConfig.getMaxRate();
}

Comment: Reading your problem from the comment is not that easy. Can you please edit your question with your progress and change you have made and the problems you are having?

Comment: Hi Araknoid, I have edited my question and mentioned the progress as per your suggestions.

Comment: Seems you are not assigning any value to the variable maxRate. If you have a default value you should assign it in the declaration of the variable or in constructor of the class A. Check my answer as i edited it.

Comment: I dont have a default value of maxRate. I am getting the value of maxRate from the function propConf.getMaxRate(); as I mentioned in my code. This will be any integer that will be assigned by the propConf.getMaxRate() fn and will not be 9.

Comment: Once you make a new instance of the class A you have not assigned a value to the maxRate variable. You should somehow assign execute the method dconfig() before read the variable. If not wrong, you could add the execution of the method dConfig() to a constructor of the class A. In this way, each time you make a new object of type A, it have loaded the property configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You *really* need to revisit [Object Oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) concepts, from the grounds up. I seriously suspect, that your problem is deeper than a variable visibility issue, and is rather related to an improper class structure...

To directly deal with this scenario, without going deeper, this approach can work:

```
public class MyClass {
    //instance variable: this can be different in 
    //each instances of this class. Now we initialize it to null
    private Integer maxRate=null; 

    private modelAndView dConfig(){

        //IMPORTANT!!!!!! Don't **declare** a new variable maxRate!
        // Your code Integer maxRate = 9; **declares a new one**
        // that would hide your class variable with a enw variable, 
        // whose scope is the method only

        maxRate = 9; //this sets the instance variable
        //this only happens when running the method
        //... I assume there are quirte some code here

    }

    /**
     * This function is available for each MyClass instance, and retrieves the
     * coresponding maxRate value.
     */
    public Integer getMaxRate() { 
         return maxRate;
    }

    //... other code
}
```

**EDIT**

I see you have trouble using this construct. Please heed my advice, and read what OOP is all about. You are trying to run withoout not even being capable of sitting up!

From a function in class B you need to do this:

```
public ModelAndView save() {

    A a = new A(); //created class A -- initialized maxRate to null!!
    //now need to run the method that sets the instance variable:
    a.dConfig(); // maxRate set to 9, or whatever.

    //don't use single char variable names! also, f is for float, if something!
    Integer maxRate = a.getMaxRate();

    //surprise. 
    logger.debug("F is" +f); 
}
```

As you didn't disclose your full code, I can only guess what you try to achieve...

Also some advices, as you seem to need guidance:

- read up on variable scopes in Java
- read up on OOP
- adhere to [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)
- learn about Clean Code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter method to get the value of that variable but you you need it to declare as instance variable.

```
public class A {
    private Integer maxRate;

    public Integer getMaxRate() {
        return this.maxRate;
    }

    private modelAndView dConfig(){
        this.maxRate = 9;
    } 
}
```

Comment: No such thing as _global variable_ in Java. What you refer to is an instance variable!